# NetBeans package untrusted macOS

Tags: macos, installation, netbeans

I'm trying to install NetBeans 8.0.1 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7

I need that specific version for university.

But it prompts an error message I've never seen in 4 years using mac: "the package baseide-8.0.1.pkg is untrusted"

baseid-8.0.1.pkg is a package inside the NetBeans8.0.1.pkg which I downloaded from official site.

Things I tried already?

- Give full access to the Oracle certificate
- Change system date to 3 months before the certificate expires
- Install it via terminal: brew cask install http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.0.1/final/bundles/netbeans-8.0.1-macosx.dmg

(Non) Installation proccess:
[Certificate problem prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkJf4.png)

[Certificate is trusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKrZI.png)

[After the typical steps, installation fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsgOO.png)

So... what can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ brew cask install netbeans-java-se
```